# How can I combine two audios into one, but using the length of the first audio?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

There are two audios. I need to connect them to each other (two channels), but with the same length as the first. I found a command on Stack Overflow that partially solves my problem: `ffmpeg -i AgAD3RMAAvgr.ogg -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=longest output.mp3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `duration=first`:

```
ffmpeg -i AgAD3RMAAvgr.ogg -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=first output.mp3
```

See [amix filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix).